# Responsive Layout: Mobile views not working!

Tags: css, responsive

I have CSS that works PERFECTLY outside of SharePoint but the moment I put it into SharePoint, it seems to break.

Funny thing is, it only breaks when the width is smaller than that of a tablet - so basically only Mobile view! The Responsive RS-Menu (main menu at the top) works great too, even in mobile view. But my content does not work :(

**THE PROBLEM**

The content floats to the left as it should, so multiple divs across the page now float to be one on top of the other. The issue is their **width** does not resize. They overflow across the window so you have to scroll right.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="s4-workspace">
<div id="s4-bodyContainer">
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">        
    <div id="header" style="background-color:#363839;">
       <div class="container clearfix">
         RESPONSIVE MENU! WORKS REALLY WELL ALWAYS
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
       <div class="content-wrap">
           <div class="container clearfix">
                CONTENT! DOES NOT RESIZE :(
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

#s4-container #s4-bodyContainer #wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 320px;
}

.container { width: 280px; }

#header .container { width: 100%; }

}
```

**NOTE:** I basically have similar code for the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
```

and all of them work! It's just when the width is less than 767px do I have problems...

**NOTE 2:** The header is clearly in the masterpage coding while the div's contained in the content-container was put in there using the **script editor**. But it's strange as all the content within script editor is being affected by my CSS AND JavaScript found in the masterpage...what's going on?

Comment: Are you resizing the browser window or checking in a real device? There is a difference!

Comment: Hi Arsalan - Both! :) Neither works.

Comment: ps, The content floats to the left as it should, so multiple divs across the page now float to be one on top of the other. The issue is their **width** does not resize. They overflow across the window so you have to scroll right.

Comment: Is it something to do with min-width you have given in #wrapper CSS

Comment: Try inspecting the element in browser using developer tools and see what's causing the problem.

Comment: The thing is, when I apply this code on an HTML file **not** in sharepoint, it works. there must be something within sharepoint stopping this specific code from working...Can't figure out what yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

I fixed it by finding out the div that SharePoint uses to contain the **Script Editor** snippets - in my case `.ms-rte-embedwp` and added extra code that matches my `.container` code! This fixed the issue!